# I need to specify to a deprecated test that is enabled = false?

Tags: java, maven, testng

i'm deprecating some methods and package's, to deprecate correctly i specify in javaDoc(@deprecarted) and with annotation(@Deprecated) like this:

```
*/
@Deprecated
@Test(groups = {"domini", "models"})
public class AdrecaTest extends ModelsAbstractTest
{
    /**
     * <pre>
     * @deprecated 
     * Nova ubicació:
     * <b>{@link cat.base.sca.domini.impl.AdrecaTest#comprovarEqualsIncorrecteNul()}</b>
     * </pre>
     * Comprova el mètode equals amb valors incorrectes o nul
     */
    @Deprecated
    @Test **(enabled=false)**
    public void comprovarEqualsIncorrecteNul()
    {
        IAdreca a;

        a = new Adreca();
        a.setTipusAdreca(PT_TIPUS_ADRECA);
        a.setIdEns(PT_ID_ENS);
        a.setIdEmissor(PT_ID_EMISSOR);
        a.setIdVial(PT_ID_VIAL);
        a.setIdSigles(PT_ID_SIGLES);
```

so, i need to specify that (enabled = false)?
ty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`@Ignore`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html) annotation:

```
@Deprecated
@Test
@Ignore
public void comprovarEqualsIncorrecteNul()
```

Junit will tell you that it has skipped a test:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1

You can also add a comment in the tag for documentation:

```
@Ignore("Ignoring deprecated test.")
```

More generally, you can use a `@Rule` to conditionally skip deprecated test methods in a class:

```
public class SkipDeprecated implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement stmnt, final Description d) {
        if (d.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) == null) {
            return stmnt;
        }
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                // Return an empty Statement object for those tests 
                // that shouldn't run.
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If there isn't an `@Deprecated` annotation then we continue as before. If there is one we return an empty `Statement` which effectively skips the tests.

In you test class you need to declare the rule:

```
@Rule
public final SkipDeprecated sd = new SkipDeprecated();
```

Example taken from [Mike Reedell](http://www.mikereedell.com/2011/12/15/JUnit-Conditional-Ignore-Using-Rules.html) and modified slightly.

As Mike points out this isn't perfect as the test is marked as passed. I did some more googling and came across [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/116#issuecomment-6546971), it's very old but summarises the issues with skipping tests in rules quite nicely.

**EDIT**

After a bit of experimentation the following seems to work very well with JUnit 4.11

```
public class SkipDeprecated implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement stmnt, final Description d) {
        if (d.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class) == null) {
            return stmnt;
        }
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Test is deprecated.");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This leverages JUnit's [`Assume`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) API and throws an `AssumptionViolatedException` from the `Statement` that is used for `@Deprecated` tests. This causes JUnit to think that the test is not applicable in these circumstances and report it as skipped - which is preferable to it being reported as passed as happens in the no-op case.